# Dynamically load xml into WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

How would I populate a WPF datagrid from XML that that I only know it will contain a range of elements but not the name or attributes?

When I get the data it is in the shape of an array of XmlNodes. Is that useful at all?

Ive tried all sorts of combinations woth XmlDataProvider etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your desired outcome, Magnus? Can you perhaps post an example of some inputs and how you'd like the grid to output them?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
            var sb = new StringBuilder("<root>");
            foreach (var node in xmlNodes)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(node.OuterXml);
            }
            sb.AppendLine("</root>");
            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(sb.ToString()));


            return ds.Tables[0];
```

a bit ugly I know so by all means let me know if you have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to construct `DataSet` from `xml` and bind binding dataset.

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="true"/>
```

C#

```
string myXMLfile = @"C:\myfile.xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// Create new FileStream with which to read the schema.
System.IO.FileStream fsReadXml = new System.IO.FileStream 
    (myXMLfile, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
try
{
    ds.ReadXml(fsReadXml);
    dataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Table[0].DefaultView; 
    // or  dataGrid1.DataSource = ds;    
}
finally
{
    fsReadXml.Close();
}
```